# Jenkins Cobertura build - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jenkins, cobertura

I have a test class `ProcessorTest` with the lines

```
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(convert);
DBOb = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonObj.toString());
```

The XML class is from [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html). The class is used else where in the code without a problem.

Everything runs fine on localhost (i.e., all Maven and JUnit tests execute).

When I pushed to Jenkins I get this error:

**Jenkins Error**

```
Error Details
net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/TouchCollector

Stack Trace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/TouchCollector
    at org.json.XML.__cobertura_init(XML.java)
    at org.json.XML.<clinit>(XML.java)
    at ProcessorTest.classSetup(ProcessorTest.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 26 more
```

I'm using Jenkins 1.553 and the Cobertura plugin 1.9.6.

How do I fix this?

The project structure is like this:

```
-- project1
     |
     | - core
     | - Tests (includes the tests that fail)


-- org.json
     |
     | - XML.class
```

When pushed to Jenkins I assume the `org.json` project is unavailable for the tests.

Answer (score 2):

This exception and stack trace is misleading; it actually results from not having [SLF4J + ch.qos.logback](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/6) included in your classpath (the `.ant/lib` path or some other classpath available to ant). Cobertura (up to and including 2.1.1, at least) has a specific requirement for the `ch.qos.logback` SLF4J implementation. If this SLF4J implementation is not included, then the following stack trace can result:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/TouchCollector
    at [org.package.ClassName].__cobertura_init([ClassName].java)
    at [org.package.ClassName].<clinit>([ClassName].java)
    at [org.package.ClassName]Test.[method]([ClassName]Test.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

In my case, I already had `slf4j-simple-1.7.14.jar` in my `.ant/lib` classpath, and I needed to remove it and replace it with [logback-core-1.0.13.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.13) and [logback-classic-1.0.13.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.13). After that, my instrumented test cases executed without this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a Java version different in your Jenkins machine. Try to install exactly the same version than you have on local.
More info here: https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/52

Comment: Both Java Versions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavior could also be related to a different Maven version on your Jenkins build machine than you use locally. It would also be of interest which version of the `cobertura-maven-plugin` you are using in your `pom.xml`.

The pure `Cobertura library` itself (bundled with the maven plugin of your project) uses a bunch of dependencies which might be in conflict with the Cobertura integration of the Jenkins environment. Try to check for `asm.jar` in your dependency tree. Maybe this causes runtime trouble in the jenkins environment as well.

A setup that works in my institution (with projects that include `org.json` dependencies):

- latest Jenkins version `1.596` in combination with the Jenkins Cobertura-Plugin `1.9.6`
- latest `cobertura-maven-plugin` maven plugin for various projects in version `2.6`

My strong guess: It is not about the `JSON` stuff itself, but about the environment of your setup; your Jenkins version `1.553` is a bit outdated. I would advice you to go for an upgrade if possible with your admins/other projects.

Comment: Its not a conflict with asm I have checked that. The `cobertura-maven-plugin` version is 2.6. I will look into the feasibility of updating Jenkins.

Comment: Did you find a way to update Jenkins on your VM/Machine? Was this a solution to the problem, as suggested in my answer?